# What's the word for using power in a morally unacceptable way?

Tags: single-word-requests

As we know, some people from the show business have recently been accused of multiple cases of sexual harassment. What would be the precise term for such abuse of power?

Comment: Why not just use "abuse"? In this context the word means a wrong use. So isn't that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 3):

'Malfeasance' could be the word you are looking for!
Merriam Webster defines it as:

illegal or dishonest activity especially by a public official or a corporation

[Full Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malfeasance)

> : wrongdoing or misconduct especially by a public official

Examples:

•The investigation has uncovered evidence of corporate malfeasance.

•A campaign to impeach the governor for malfeasance in office

Hope it helps!

Comment: Definitely a good option @Adarsh C! To improve your answer along this site pattern, please edit your answer to  quote a standard definition of the word from a reputed dictionary, and also provide the link to the web page containing that definition.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Thankyou for suggestions, my friend. I am new here, and do not know much about the environment and fundamentals here. Looking forward to learning a lot from you guys!

Comment: You are most welcome @Adarsh. I am from India only and English.SE is the place to be for all those who love English language and usage!

Comment: Here are some tips for dictionary entries: use block quotes for the part you copied (to do this, put a ">" character at the start of each line of the quote), name the dictionary (as you've done), and include a link (the link button in 'edit mode' helps). I've added a link and block quote for you (I only quoted the definition because I didn't find the examples on the linked page). Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back my changes.

Comment: Thankyou for your conducive advice @Lawrence. I will definitely have this thing in mind next time.